# Date and hour format with seconds

Tags: date-preferences

this date and hour format should work: `%d/%m/%Y %k:%M:%S`
but I'm not getting the seconds: `17/02/2021 9:15:%S`

Is `%S` compatible in CiviCRM?

Comment: I came here to post the same question.

Comment: I've submitted an issue in gitlab: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, (custom) date formatting in civicrm is handled by this function:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Utils/Date.php#L300

You'll see at about line 410 that there's no substitution for seconds.

Sounds like a not-very-difficult feature waiting to be added.

Comment: works fine. we'll do a PR on Git